# jquery.validate - multiple plugins with same name?

Tags: jquery-validate

**multiple plugins with same name?**

I started my search for a jquery validation with a google search. The top few links lead to confusion because one page on the jquery site is [a plugin authored by mfranz](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryvalidate) whereas another link leads to [a plugin authored by Jörn Zaefferer](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) which is linked from jquery.com to an offsite domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter link is the official plugin from JQuery. That can be downloaded here:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

or you can use CDN

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js

The other link looks like it started in 2010, whereas JQuery Validate is there since 2006